# Android listing installed applications related database

Tags: android, database, list

I'm listing installed applications on a ListView. I want to get the applications that **have not been** inserted to the database.

For example:
ALL INSTALLED APPLICATIONS
com.a.b
com.c.d
com.e.f
com.g.h
com.j.k
DATABASE RECORDS
com.c.d
com.g.h
I want the result to do that:
RESULT:
com.a.b
com.e.f
com.j.k
My code here:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = vt2.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT uygulamaAdi FROM ivu WHERE kategori='" + kategori + "'", null);
c.moveToFirst();

uygList = new ArrayList<String>();
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

final List<String> paketAdlari = new ArrayList<String>();
final List<String> islemTurleri = new ArrayList<String>();

List<ApplicationInfo> paketler = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (ApplicationInfo paketBilgi : paketler) {

    if (paketBilgi.packageName != c.getString(0)) {

        uygList.add("   ( + )     " + paketBilgi.loadLabel(pm).toString() + "     (Yükle)   ");
        paketAdlari.add(paketBilgi.packageName);
        islemTurleri.add("kaldir");

        if (sayi<c.getCount()-1) {
            sayi++;
            c.moveToNext();
        }

    }

}
```

As my code, it gives the result like that:
com.a.b
com.c.d
com.e.f
com.j.k

It only removes the last record. I want to remove all the previous records...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way of doing this is either to send up a single search for each application installed to see if its in the DB or not, taking advantage of the power of the db.  Or if that isn't performing well to take all the applications in the db, add them to a HashSet, and then walk the list of installed apps checking 1 by 1 if its in the hashset.

Comment: I wrote a SQL query into the loop and as you said, I made it for each record. Thank you so much...